# backbone halt a slow request response

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

Is there a method of aborting or "no longer listening" to a response in backbone -- in order to avoid making, ordering and otherwise processing a collection that will not be used by the user. He or she has moved on, so to speak.

Possibly someone has added that to their Backbone.sync.

Or perhaps add a flag in the collection.parse function.